# ViewStub as a ListActivity's empty view

Tags: android, android-listfragment, viewstub

I have a `ListActivity` that displays user data. The first time the user loads the list, it's empty, so I use the "empty view" functionality, by giving a view the ID `android.R.id.empty`. This view isn't just a "no items" message: it's a kind of quick-start guide, showing the user how to create data items that will show up in the list.

Because the quick-start guide is quite a complicated layout, with lots of pictures, I don't want the overhead of loading it and keeping it in memory, in the common case when the list is not empty. For this reason, I'd like to 'hide' it behind a `ViewStub`.

While the activity is loading, will the list make the 'empty' view visible, loading the `ViewStub`? The list adapter is set in `onCreate`, before calling `setContentView`, so it's before the list is shown. If it will do this, is there a way to avoid it without replacing the 'empty view' functionality completely? Obviously it would be possible to change the visibility myself at the appropriate time, but I did it this way to reduce the amount of code in my activity.

Answer (score 0):

It is always good in Android programming to do these kind of stuff to do yourself manually. You can just get the `ViewStub` manually to a variable and inflate it if the list is in fact an empty list. It is not very hard at all. You only should look the adapter size when your list is loaded completely. If the size of the adapter is 0, then you can get the `ViewStub` and inflate it.

Comment: If it's always good to do it manually, why does ListView have the 'empty view' feature at all?

Comment: I should have said, it is alwyas good to do it manually if it is more complicated then the default behaviour.